# broadcast video from camera to 10000s of andrioid or ios application users using webrtc

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, live-streaming, openwebrtc

I want to broadcast video captured from extrenal  camera and want to through live video on android and ios mobile application with least latency.

I am looking for help, either **webrtc** could help me out in this problem. If answer is yes. Kindly guide me in this Regard.

**Requirements:**

- That is one way communication like Television, peers will just watch
  video.
- I want to scale my architect up-to thousands to millions of users(android/ios) in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to build a highly scalable broadcast system then webrtc may not be the right choice. You should look for streaming servers which are more suited for broadcast.

For a complete list of streaming engines open the link below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems

Some popular ones are wowza, red5, nimble etc.